# Scraping XML off a specific YouTube Movie Page (YouTube API)

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to scrape this page?

http://www.youtube.com/movie?v=mDqLG28m_Eo

I've been using this URL to call the YouTube API:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/mDqLG28m_Eo?v=2

The problem is that it seems to be calling from this page instead:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDqLG28m_Eo

How can I call from the main movie page instead of that trailer page? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: I won't say that there is no API available for youtube movies, however I can at least say that the API you're using is only for videos. Make sure to read over the documentation a bit more: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a good answer :D
To be honest, the YouTube movie API sucks. Try to simply copy + paste a demo URL from the YouTube API Movies documentation, you'll get an invalid request error. I already reported the bugs, but the dev team was like "It isn't worth the effort to fix this". The movie API does also not support the `?q=` parameter, but this is what you can do: Make a normal video search and specify that only movies should be returned:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/Movies?alt=json&v=2&q=Life%20in%20a%20day&alt=json
```

Not sure if there are videos in the feed that are not YouTube movies, but you can determine it by checking if `media:credit` exists.

Here is a demo of your scraped movie "Prometheus" in live: http://tuberapp.com/movie-mDqLG28m_Eo